# Why I am getting $parse error when use it on object with array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two json files. I am getting them like this:

```
var fr, en;
$.getJSON('fr.json', function(data) {
    fr = data;
}).complete(function() {
    ...
});

$.getJSON('en.json', function(data) {
    en = data;
}).complete(function() {
    ...
});
```

This files are locale files. I want to test them. I want to compare objects fr and en by property names, so unit test will show, when something is missing in locale file.

To get what properties are missing in EN locale I am using this algorithm:

1. Get all object paths, like a.b.c, a.b.e, a.d.x etc in FR locale
2. Then I use `$parse(*path*)(fr);` and if it returns something -> EN locale
   has same property as FR locale has.

So my problem. I have such string in file fr. 
"some": { "numbers": ["one", "two", "three"] ... }
In first step, I got such property paths:

```
some.numbers.0
some.numbers.1
some.numbers.2
```

And when I am trying to $parse this paths on EN locale I got this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.0' is an unexpected token at column 15 of the expression [addForm.messages.numbers.0] starting at [.0].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=.0&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=25&p3=some.numbers.0&p4=.0
```

How can I get working $parse on objects, which contain arrays? Or is there any other way to do what I need?

Comment: object doesn't have those properties, `numbers` is an array. Need to use proper javascript object/array notation

Comment: use `some.numbers[0]` instead of `some.numbers.0`. `some.numbers.0` is an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl mentioned in his comment to the question:

> Object doesn't have those properties, numbers is an array. Need to use
>   proper javascript object/array notation

So, I need use

```
some.numbers[0]
some.numbers[1]
etc
```

instead of

```
some.numbers.0
```